# Can I use Exporter in Perl to export a Struct?

Tags: perl, struct, exporter

I have defined a struct in a module (using Class:Struct) and I am confused as to how it gets exported to another module.

```
package MyPackage;
use Class::Struct;
use Exporter 'import';
@EXPORT = qw( function1 function2 );
struct(MyStruct=>{'type'=>'$', 'other'=>'$'});
```

Now if I include MyPackage in a different module, I can directly create a MyStruct variable:

```
package OtherPackage;
use MyPackage qw(function1 function2);
use Data::Dumper;

sub my_function {
    print Dumper(MyStruct);
}
```

and if I call my_function, it prints out the empty struct as expected.

However, and this is my confusion, I don't know how to add it to the @EXPORT, or even if I should. Can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exporter isn't appropriate here. You said it yourself: you can `use MyPackage;` and initialize `MyStruct`s. The example you gave, if written without the convenience of Class::Struct, would look something like this:

```
package MyPackage;
use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT = qw(function1 function2);
sub function1 { ... }
sub function2 { ... }
1;

package MyStruct;
sub new # Constructor
{ 
    my $self = shift; 
    my %args = @_;
    return bless(
        {
            'MyStruct::type'  => $args{type},
            'MyStruct::other' => $args{other},
        },
        $self,
    );
}

sub type # Setter/getter for type
{
    my ($self, $set) = shift;
    return $set ? $self->{type} = $set
                : $self->{type};
}

sub other # Setter/getter for other
{
    ... # So on and so forth
}
1;
```

The difference is that Class::Struct takes the "blueprint" and writes the `MyStruct` class for you. From `perlobj`: A class is simply a package. A class provides methods that expect to operate on objects.

It's pretty confusing to put two packages together in a single file (which is what Class::Struct does implicitly) so instead you could separate them.

MyPackage.pm:

```
package MyPackage;
use parent qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(function1 function2);
sub function1 { ... }
sub function2 { ... }
1;
```

MyStruct.pm:

```
package MyStruct;
use Class::Struct;
struct( 
    MyStruct => { 
        'type' => '$',
        'other' => '$'
    }
);
1;
```

It wasn't clear from your question, but if `MyPackage::function1()` is meant to operate on the data contained in MyStruct objects, you should scrap `MyPackage` altogether and provide it as a method in MyStruct:

```
package MyStruct;
use Class::Struct;
struct( 
    MyStruct => { 
        'type' => '$',
        'other' => '$'
    }
);
sub function1
{
    my $self = shift;
    print "This is function1 in $self\n";
}
1;
```

Finally, instead of exporting anything from MyStruct, just use it like an object:

```
use MyStruct;
my $instance = MyStruct->new( type => 'foo' ); # Instantiating
$instance->other('bar'); # Setting
print $instance->type;   # Getting
```